# Is it possible to change the path of a css file that is registered through wp_enqueue_style()?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

The theme I am using already calls the `wp_enqueue_style` function to enqueue a css file.

I want to whether it is possible to change the css file path before it is actually outputted on the page.

Why I want to do this?

Basically, I want to check if it is a dev or prod environment. Based on that I want to include either the uncompressed or compressed file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you are looking for the `style_loader_src` filter?

For example:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 
    function ( $src ){

        // ... your stuff ... 

        return $src;
    }
);
```

Similarly there exists the `script_loader_src` filter.

There's also the `base_url` property of the global `$wp_scripts` and `$wp_styles` objects, but I think that's only used for enqueued native styles and scripts.